# What could cause invalid distance too far back and how to modify zlib to fix it?

Tags: c++, c, zlib

I am trying to decompress a raw stream of data from 3rd party source. The data is compressed with zlib library (version 1.2.13) and transmitted over TCP protocol. I was able to capture both compressed and uncompressed stream of data using WireShark and mix of reverse engineering methods:

Compressed form: `0xCA 0x05 0xDB 0xC8 0xE8 0x07 0x22 0x01 0x00`

Uncompressed form: `0x6D 0x4D 0x7D 0x9B 0x7C 0x07 0x01 0x4E 0x7D 0x9B 0x7C 0x07 0x00`

```cpp
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char in[9] = {0xCA, 0x05, 0xDB, 0xC8, 0xE8, 0x07, 0x22, 0x01, 0x00};
    unsigned char out[65535] = {0};

    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;

    int ret = inflateInit2(&strm, -15);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return ret;

    strm.next_in = (unsigned char *) in;
    strm.avail_in = 9;
    strm.next_out = (unsigned char *) out;
    strm.avail_out = 65535;
    strm.total_out = 0;

    ret = inflate(&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
```

Initially, the `inflate` function returned -3 (with message "invalid distance too far back"). I then recompiled zlib with two modifications: added `DINFLATE_ALLOW_INVALID_DISTANCE_TOOFAR_ARRR` flag and changed `sane = 0` in `inflateResetKeep` function to allow invalid distance.

After these modifications, calling `inflate` function I am getting the following result (in output buffer):

`0x6D 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`

I've tried to debug this deflate stream with `infgen` tool but it gives me an error saying `incomplete deflate stream`.

There is a chance that the deflate stream comes from modified zlib library (but I am not sure about it). Could anyone point me in right direction, please?

Comment: *The data is compressed with zlib library*  That doesn't specify the actual data format.  Is is it `ZLIB` data per [RFC-1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt), `GZIP` data per [RFC-1952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt), or raw `DEFLATE` data per [RFC-1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt)?  It looks like you're treating the data as raw `DEFLATE` data.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I checked how the binary calls the ```inflateInit2``` function and it uses -15 as windowBits - so I assumed it's raw deflate data.

Comment: I'm sorry, then, I'm missing something.  You have a binary that successfully recovers the uncompressed data from the compressed stream?  In that case, what's the question?  Or you have a binary that *does not* successfully recover the uncompressed data, in which case how can you rely on it to tell you about the actual form of the data?

Comment: My guess would be you've not correctly captured the data or the data is being manipulated somehow before being passed to zlib

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've the binary which I don't have access to source code and I must replicate the compression / decompression mechanism. The data is 100% correct since I've captured it from the process memory after the ```inflate``` function call.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I am more convinced about any modifications to zlib library by this 3rd party company.

Comment: Ok.  Is zlib statically linked into the binary?  In that case, you might look into decompiling the relevant functions.  Or is zlib dynamically linked?  In that case, you can be sure that the binary is using whatever version of zlib your system provides, unmodified.  But either way, it is conceivable that the program modifies the data after compression.  That's not likely to be something that you could resolve by hacking zlib.

Comment: Perhaps you can re-run your test with the same data, but using the original/official zlib library, and see if the same error message occurs there.  If not, that's good evidence that the third-party's library-modifications are the cause of the error.  If the problem persists, then my suspicion would be that there is a flaw in the compressed data, but in any case you'd have an easily-reproducible test case that you could take to the zlib library maintainers to confirm or deny that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the zlib is statically linked into the binary - I even dumped the disassembled code of original zlib's ```inflate``` function and the binary's ```inflate``` function and tried to compare it - but it's over 3k+ lines of asm code to compare.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I tried to ```inflate``` the test data with original zlib library and it failed with error mentioned in the post (invalid distance, too far back).

Comment: I said "decompile", not "disassemble".  There are tools that attempt to recreate C source code from binary code, and I mean engaging one of these.  It will still take some effort to reconcile the result with the zlib source, but it should be a lot easier than working from from assembly code.  With that said, however, if the data are being mangled, my initial guess would be that it is done outside the scope of zlib.

Comment: @szulak If you have the raw data in a file, what does the `file` utility print?  `file datafie`  just might be able to tell you the data format.

Comment: Perhaps a preset dictionary is required to inflate the input? If the input had a 16-bit zlib header, one of the bits in the header would indicate whether a preset dictionary was needed, but since the header is missing from the input, who knows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data is a fragment of a deflate stream. Those bits disassembled are:

```
! infgen 3.0 output
!
fixed
literal 'm
match 5 114
infgen warning: distance too far back (114/1)
literal 1 'N
match 4 6
end
!
stored
infgen warning: incomplete deflate data
```

It needs five bytes from 113 bytes before the start of this data, which would be part of an earlier portion of the deflate stream. Later, four of those five bytes that you don't have get repeated again.

It is not possible to get the data you are expecting just from that fragment of a deflate stream. The `0x4D 0x7D 0x9B 0x7C 0x07` you are expecting has to come from somewhere else.